# Using Eloquent with Spaces in Table Columns

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel and have a table that has columns with spaces.  I can't change the names of the columns.  I am trying to use Eloquent and have tried many things to get this to work but can't.  I thought this would be the answer:

{{$provider->'Entity Type Code'}}

Thanks

Comment: Try dumping the model to find out how Laravel mapped these fields for you: `dd($provider)`. I would however recommend to rename these columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{}` brackets

```
{{ $provider->{'Entity Type Code'} }}
```

Or use another variables

```
$variable_name = 'Entity Type Code';
{{ $provider->$variable_name }}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  The first one did it